# Editing a local resource's visibility in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fairly new to WPF and have struggled trying to find an answer to this so maybe I am going about it the wrong way.

I have a ContextMenu that I wish to use multiple places so I have it defined as a Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MainContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Select All"        Click="SelectAllButton_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Clear All"         Click="ClearAllButton_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Export"            Click="ExportButton_Click"     Name="ExportCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Priority"          Click="PriorityButton_Click"   Name="PriorityCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Cancel"            Click="CancelButton_Click"     Name="CancelCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Reallocate"        Click="ReallocateButton_Click" Name="ReallocateCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Release"           Click="ReleaseButton_Click"    Name="ReleaseCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Hazard"            Click="HazardButton_Click"     Name="HazardCM"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Reset"             Click="ResetButton_Click"      Name="ResetCM"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

I also have a Menu with items with identical headers and click handlers but the Menu is not a resource since I only needed to place it once.  With the Menu I am able to edit the visibility of certain MenuItems in codebehind.  I would like to be able to do the same to my ContextMenu.

How can I access an individual ContextMenu MenuItem and set its visibility in code behind if my ContextMenu is a locally defined static resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Custom Controls in WPF. You can extend a WPF control where you can add all your Menus / Menus Items and handle them as objects using XAML.

http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

After doing that, inside the Window you want to use your custom Menu, you need to add the namespace like in:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YourProject.YourControl"
```

And then you can use your menu like this:

```
<controls:YourControl>
```

Also take a look at DataTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContextMenu ctxmenu = (ContextMenu)this.Resources["MainContextMenu"];
```

And if you assign this context menu to say Button:Btn1, then `Btn1.ContextMenu` will give you the context menu of button Btn1.

To access a particular menuitem, you have `btn1.ContextMenu.Items` collections to play with.